# AngularJs Bind Directive parameter to mdDialog's Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Hi guys I have a very complicated issue.

I have created a reusable directive and now i want to take the user's parameter value and bind it to my form inside the directive.

At the **user's side**, they are able to call the directive by:

```
<test-app></test-app>
```

Then they are able to pass in parameters into the directive :

```
<test-app user-email="test@hotmail.com"></test-app> 

 OR 

<test-app user-email="{{ userEmail }} "></test-app>
 //They can take value from their own controller.
```

At my **Own side** at the directive , main.js :

```
angular.module('TestModule').controller('MainCtrl',['$mdDialog',function($mdDialog) {
 this.openDialog = openDialog;

function openDialog(){
      $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogCtrl as dialog',
      templateUrl: 'dialog.html'
      });

    }
    }]);

angular.module('TestModule').directive('testApp',function(){
      return { 
      controller: 'MainCtrl as main',
      scope: { 
      userEmail :'@'

      },
      restrict : 'E' ,
      templateUrl : 'FormButton.html'
     }
    });

angular.module('TestModule').controller('DialogCtrl',['$mdDialog',function($mdDialog,$scope){

   function submit(){
      etc etc . . 
    }

}
```

At the FormButton.html:

```
<md-button ng-click="main.openDialog()"> </md-button>
```

At the dialog.html:

```
<md-dialog>
   <form>
      etc , etc

     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="userEmail">
      etc , etc
   </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Issue: I need to pass in the **userEmail value** from the user side and bind it to the form so that when the user opens the form , the value is there.

I think because of the templateUrl , the convention way of binding the model doesn't work.

What i have tried: 
1) I tried ng-model to bind but the form is in another page so it was not able to read the value.

2) I wanted to pass the value from the directive to controller , I research online but found no viable solution to this problem.

can anyone Kindly Help with this solution?

Comment: use `bindToController: true` in your directive.

Comment: `ng-model="user.email"` should be `userEmail`

Comment: @Claies i added it in, but it doesn't have any changes to the output

Comment: @PankajParkar changed. But it doesn't seem to affect it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the $mdDialog api [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#show), especially at the `locals` option.

> locals - {object=}: An object containing key/value pairs. The keys
>   will be used as names of values to inject into the controller. For
>   example,

```
this.userEmail = 'someone@neeae.com';
function openDialog(){
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'DialogCtrl as dialog',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
    locals: {
      email: this.userEmail  // `this` is the main controller (parent).
    }
  });
}
```

In the html:

```
<test-app user-email="{{ main.userEmail }} "></test-app>
```

DialogCtrl

```
angular.module('TestModule').controller('DialogCtrl', ['$mdDialog', '$scope', 'email', function($mdDialog, $scope, email) {
  // Here you can use the user's email  
  this.userEmail = email;
  function submit() {
    //etc etc ..
  }
}]);
```

At the **dialog.html**:

```
<md-dialog>
  <form>
   <!-- etc , etc-->

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" data-ng-model="dialog.userEmail">
```

Comment: This works ! But can i ask how to pass the parameter value from the directive to controller so i can bind it to this.userEmail ??

Comment: By using two way binding, i.e. use `userEmail :'='` instead of `userEmail :'@'`. That also allows you to drop the necessity of use {{}}, in `<test-app user-email="main.userEmail"></test-app>`

Comment: i used userEmail : '=' and got a parse:lexerr error. is there another way to do so ?

Comment: forgot to remove the {{}} braces sorry. But it still doesn't work

Comment: sorry ! solved it already ! if you dont mind, can u kindly help with my other questions that i had opened !

Comment: Which one dude?

Comment: the angular theme !

Answer (score 0):

```
<test-app email="test@hotmail.com"></test-app>
```

You are passing value in "email" variable. But you are not mapping this variable in directive scope.

Try this once.

```
<test-app userEmail="test@hotmail.com"></test-app>
```

Comment: typo error on top sorry. I had it as user-email at my site. Any more ideas on how i can solve it ?